# Sharing content using the Facebook Share Dialog inside ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, interface, callback

I have a custom ArrayAdapter with a share button for every item. I use the facebook share dialog with no problems in regular activities, but now I can't get it to work for sharing my list items.

If I am right, the facebook share dialog needs an activity to work, well my custom ArrayAdapter does not have one, but I have to pass the data from individual items to the share dialog so it has to go inside tha arrayadapter class, right?

I was trying to use an interface to pass back the image address and name to the main activity, but it keeps crashing when I press the button.

Am I in the right direction, or is there another way to share item's data from inside a listview?

Thanks!

```
FeedGridViewAdapter (custom ArrayAdapter):

    public class FeedGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItemsSetter> {
        private Context context;
        private int layoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> data = new ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter>();
        private TextView locationName;
        private ImageView image;
        private ImageView feedUserImage;
        private TextView cityName;
        private TextView userInfo; 
        private String[] separatedLikerData;
        private FeedItemsSetter item;

        public interface facebookShareListener { 
            public void onSharePressed(String values);
        }   

        facebookShareListener mListener;    

        public FeedGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> data) {
            super(context, android.R.id.content, data); 
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed_grid, null);

                item = data.get(position);          

                TextView[] likers = new TextView[10];

                locationName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locName);
                locationName.setText(item.getTitle());

                cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
                cityName.setText(item.getCategory());

                userInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUserName);
                userInfo.setText(item.getUser());

                feedUserImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUserImage);
                Picasso.with(context)
                .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getUserId() + "/picture?type=large") 
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(90, 4))
                .resize(100, 100)         
                .centerCrop()  
                .into(feedUserImage);  

                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);          
                Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.edmondvarga.com/gastrolove/uploads/" + item.getImage())
                .into(image); 

                separatedLikerData = item.getLiker().split(",");

                if(separatedLikerData.length < 5){
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.likerNames);             
                likers[position] = new TextView(context); 
                likers[position].setText(separatedLikerData[0] + ", ");
                likers[position].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d52e2e"));
                likers[position].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                likers[position].setTextSize(13);                   

                layout.addView(likers[position]);

                likers[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {                               
                        Intent in= new Intent(context, UserProfile.class);
                        in.putExtra("user", separatedLikerData[0]);
                        in.putExtra("userId", separatedLikerData[1]);
                        context.startActivity(in);                              
                    }

                }); 
                }

               //-----------Iterface implmentation -----------------

                Button feedShare = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feedShareBtn); 
                feedShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                    @Override
                      public void onClick(View v)  {                    
                        mListener.onSharePressed("image link");
                    }
                   }); 

            return view;
        }

    }
```

Main Class:

```
...

public class OffersFragmentActivity extends Fragment implements
        OnItemClickListener, FeedGridViewAdapter.facebookShareListener {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
    ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
    View v;
    private SQLiteDataSource datasource;
    private ListView TasteMakersListView;
    private ArrayList<TasteMakers> tasteMakersList = new ArrayList<TasteMakers>();
    private TasteMakers member;
    private GridView feedGridView;
    private String user;
    private ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter>();
    protected String names;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offers_view, null, false);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                "USERINFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        user = preferences.getString("name", null);

        feedGridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.feedGridView);
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        TasteMakersListView = (ListView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.RecomendedUsersList);

        feedGridView.setFocusable(false);
        gridView.setFocusable(false);
        TasteMakersListView.setFocusable(false);

...


    @Override
    public void onSharePressed(String values) {
        System.out.println("Share button pressed!" + values);

    }

    ...
```

Logcat:

```
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): Process: com.fideli, PID: 9647
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.fideli.userimages.FeedGridViewAdapter$2.onClick(FeedGridViewAdapter.java:111)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-12 20:30:54.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an NPE, which seems to indicate that your mListener variable is null. Have you actually set the listener from your Activity?

Also, your ArrayAdapter class has a Context, which is probably an Activity if you created it from your Activity class, why not just use that and pass it to the share dialog? The share dialog can also take a Fragment if you have only a Fragment.

Comment: you right, it has to be initialized. I was searching but still didn't figured out how to initialize the listener in the case of a ArrayAdadapter.

Comment: thanks. I had to initialize the listener when adding the passing the arraylist to the custom arrayadapter: FeedGridViewAdapter feedGridAdapter = new FeedGridViewAdapter(
    getActivity(), feedList);
  feedGridAdapter.setCallback(this);
  feedGridView.setAdapter(feedGridAdapter);
  feedGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);